# Pipe grep exit code away

Tags: grep, pipe, exit

When I need to suppress some kind of output e.g.

```
foo | grep -v bar
```

But foo gives sometimes only:

```
bar
bar
bar...
```

grep will return -1. How do I transform the exit code 1 to 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could always try piping it through something else, like `cat`, to get rid of the exit code from grep - though that may be a bigger hammer than you want.

Comment: and this seems even to be Posix compliant

Comment: You can also do `|| true` if you're trying to bypass failure under `set -e`

Comment: @Daenyth Of course that transforms _every_ non-zero exit code to 0, not only 1.

Answer (score 1):

At least in bash, you can use

```
foo || (EC=$?; if [ $EC -ne 1 ]; then exit $EC; fi)
```

This changes exit code 1 to 0, and changes nothing else.

(Perhaps not POSIX-compliant, but probably a POSIX-compliant version exists.)